# Newly created Quip documents don't appear on the web page

Tags: api, automation, quip

I use `https://platform.quip.com/1/threads/new-document` endpoint to create new document. According to the documentation, if I skip `member_ids` field, the new document should be added to the current user (mine in this case) private folder. But even though I get the response that the thread was created (having its Id), it is not displayed in my private folder when I navigate to my Quip instance.

At the same time:

1. I can retrieve this thread via API by its Id
2. I can navigate to this thread on the web page using `<username>.quip.com/<thread id>`
3. After I've opened this thread, I can see it in the list of the recent threads
4. But if I try to retrieve my private folder by its Id, this thread doesn't appear under its `children` field
5. If I retrieve this thread or another thread that do show up in the folder, they both have the same `user_ids` and `shared_folder_ids` fields, that contain just my user Id

Though I understand, that I could take my private folder Id and add this thread to it explicitly using `thread/add-members` endpoint, but I generally try to implement 'copy thread' scenario and it seems that I can't directly retrieve the folder (folders) by the source thread to realize where I should put the copy. Is it a kind of bug of the API? Or how I can implement this scenario except traversing the whole user folder tree to find out which one of them the source thread belongs to?

**UPD:** it seems that newly created threads are put into `desktop` folder but I couldn't find a way to view this folder on the webpage

Comment: Haven't run into your specific issue before but I have had problems with the way threads are assigned to the favorites folder.  The API won't recognize any chat threads in the fav folder id.

Quip does not support its API.  I have found several bugs (and deviations from their documentation) in their API and websockets.  I have brought this to their attention in several different ways but they have said they are not really interested in maintaining or developing their API anymore...very sad.